# Java Mouse Event Listerner in Image

Tags: java, event-handling, mouseevent

is it possible to add mouse listener to an image for game development.
Or to any class which puts an image to a JPanel.

Comment: add event to panel

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: then please tell me how can I specify the position of the label on the JPanel?

Answer (score 2):

you could use an `JButton` with an BufferdImage for this, there you have the Standard listener for a `JButton` to work with.

Sample:

```
JButton button;
BufferedImage buttonIcon;
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

try {
   buttonIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("path")); //path of image
   button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon));
} catch (IOException e) {   
   button = new JButton(); //couldn't load Image
}

frame.getContentPane().add(button);

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(200,200);
frame.setVisible(true);
```